# Deletion an icon from a tray

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, tray

Using the code below results in that sometimes an icon remains in a tray right after call to `removeIconFromTray` method and disappears only after a user moves over an icon in tray.

```
void CMyDlg::addIconToTray()
{
    static HICON hIcon = ::LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
    NOTIFYICONDATA data;

    data.cbSize = sizeof(data);
    data.hIcon = hIcon;
    data.hWnd = m_hWnd;
    strcpy (data.szTip, m_sTrayIconTip.c_str());
    data.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    data.uID = (UINT)this;

    Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_ADD, &data);
}

void CMyDlg::removeIconFromTray()
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA data;

    data.cbSize = sizeof(data);
    data.hWnd = m_hWnd;
    data.uID = (UINT)this;

    Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_DELETE, &data);

}
```

Whats wrong in this code and how to achieve that an icon disappears from a tray as soon as a code deleting it form there finished working?

Comment: You don't check the return value of Shell_NotifyIcon.  So you cannot know when it failed, you can only watch it misbehave.  Arbitrary guess is that m_hWnd was already destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem is that you are failing to initialize your struct. You should do this:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA data = { 0 };
```

Other  than that check for errors and call GetLastError to find out what caused any error.

Comment: This is particularly important in the `NIM_DELETE` case, as the `data.uFlags` field is not being initialized, so it likely is getting set to random bits that are causing `NIM_DELETE` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

[Shell_NotifyIcon function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159.aspx)

> Deletes an icon from the status area. NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by lpdata uses the ID originally assigned to the icon when it was added to the notification area (NIM_ADD) to identify the icon to be deleted.

So, you should pass the same data of NOTIFYICONDATA to Shell_NotifyIcon function.

```
void CMyDlg::addIconToTray()
{
    static HICON hIcon = ::LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYICON));
    NOTIFYICONDATA data;

    data.cbSize = sizeof(data);
    data.hIcon = hIcon;
    data.hWnd = m_hWnd;
    strcpy (data.szTip, m_sTrayIconTip.c_str());
    data.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    data.uID = (UINT)this;

    Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_ADD, &data);
}

void CMyDlg::removeIconFromTray()
{
    NOTIFYICONDATA data;

    data.cbSize = sizeof(data);
    data.hIcon = hIcon;
    data.hWnd = m_hWnd;
    strcpy (data.szTip, m_sTrayIconTip.c_str());
    data.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
    data.uID = (UINT)this;

    Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_DELETE, &data);

}
```

This will work properly.
Or, save the data to a member variable.

Comment: You DO NOT need to do this. Specifying **only** the same HWND and ID as those used with `NIM_ADD` is enough, as those are the only fields that `NIM_DELETE` looks at (since `NIF_GUID` is not being used).

Answer (score 0):

As DavidHeffernan said, you should zero-initialize your `data` struct (you should ALWAYS zero-init any struct that you pass to a Win32 API function), eg:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA data = {0};
```

Or:

```
NOTIFYICONDATA data;
ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(data));
```

This way, any unused fields have consistent and predictable values.  In your case, when calling `NIM_DELETE`, you are not initializing `data`, so its `uFlags` field will have random bits, which is likely to cause `Shell_NotifyIcon()` to misinterpret the content of your `NOTIFYICONDATA` and fail, and thus your icon is not removed.